# Classifying genitive

Tags: grammar, possessives, genitive-construction

‎Can we use genitive constructions in sentences like this:

The cat loved Jill with all his cat's heart;

...or should it be "with all his cat heart"?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be: **....with all his/her/its heart**.  No repetition of **cat** or **cat's**.

Comment: Thank you, Ronald!

Comment: The cat's  heart is in the right place.

Comment: Would you say *my human's heart is still beating* or *my human heart is still beating*? (In theory, if I had a human slave, I could say the first, but that's a contrived meaning, and not the sense that's meant in the question.) *Cat*, in this question, is used as an attributive noun, not as a possessive.

Comment: I suggest (slightly "facetious") ***catty*** rather than ***cat*** or ***cat's***. Google Books has no instances at all of *with all his **dog** heart* that I can see. There are a couple of instances of *with all his **dog's** heart*, but *with all his **doggy** heart* is much more common.

Comment: "My human heart" sounds nicer to me, but at the same time how do you (natives) say things like this: "his policeman('s) courage", "his boxer('s) reflexes", "his dog('s) loyalty (the loyalty, comparable to that of a dog)", "my writer('s) imagination" and the like. In my language I can say "она лю́бит его́ все́м свои́м СОБА́ЧЬИМ се́рдцем" which literally means (she loves him him with all her DOG'S heart). On the second thought, I use this adjective to fill the sentence with emotions, this must be a stylistic thing that is expressed differently in English...

Comment: @VsevolodIV: As suggested by Ronald, ***none*** of these qualifiers for ***heart*** are particularly idiomatic in English. But at least the diminutive / facetious ***catty / doggy*** versions do turn up from time to time. If you don't want that facetious element, I advise you to follow Ronald's advice.

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica, Wow, I've never heard of it before! Thank you very much! Do you think there exists a similarly elegant way around the other clumsy constructions I made above?

Comment: I can't imagine any context where you'd be likely to qualify *[with all his] **heart*** with anything like ***human***, so there's nothing to think about there.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica 'catty' is rather more pejorative than 'doggy'!

Comment: @WeatherVane: Not necessarily, even in "non-facetious" contexts. And so far as I'm concerned that issue simply doesn't arise in facetious / whimsical contexts like *Rover's doggy heart* and *Kitty's catty heart*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Qualifying *heart* with *human* would be easy to do (and perhaps even necessary) in some science fiction or fantasy stories.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I though of that possible context just as I clicked "Add Comment". Point conceded! :)